# Can I use a min-height for table, tr or td?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show some details of a receive in a table.

I want that table to have a min height to show the products. So if there is only one product, the table would have at least some white space at the end. In the other hand if there are 5 or more products, it won't have that empty space.

I have tried this CSS:

```
table,td,tr{
  min-height:300px;
}
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's not a nice solution, but try it like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Lorem</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Ipsum</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and set the divs to the min-height:

```
div {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: @SackySan you need to give the divs classes and then make this rule apply to that class only

Comment: It is actually a nices solution! The most upvoted answer is just misleading as it doesn't allow to have the equivalent of a `min-height` on all rows with a set `height` on specific rows. You have my vote sir!

Answer (score 530):

`height` for `td` works like `min-height`:

```css
td {
  height: 100px;
}
```

instead of

```css
td {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

Table cells will grow when the content does not fit.

https://jsfiddle.net/qz70zps4/

Comment: In my Google Chrome (version 47.0.2526.106 m) running on a Windows 7, I found that setting the `height` of a `td` actually is processed as a `padding` top and bottom, which may introduce some layout problem as you think it's really a `height` space. It doesn't show as a style or as a computed style in the dev tools, but when you put your mouse over the inspected html element it's shown on the screen.

Comment: but the question was on min-height that does not work! what happens if you have a long text and needs another line with height it will get messed up

Comment: like @CMS said, he asked about `min-height` not `height` however as @frank explains below it behaves the same for `table td`. So maybe this needs a bit better explanation.

Answer (score 39):

The solution without `div` is used a pseudo element like `::after` into first `td` in row with `min-height`. Save your HTML clean.

```
table tr td:first-child::after {
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   min-height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables,
> inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined.

So try wrapping the content in a div, and give the div a `min-height`
[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VfPNN/)

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:300px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="min-height: 100px; background-color: #ccc">
                    Hello World !
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="min-height: 100px; background-color: #f00">
                    Good Morning !
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7):

if you set style="height:100px;" on a td if the td has content that grows the cell more than that, it will do so no need for min height on a td.

Answer (score 0):

Tables and table cells don't use the `min-height` property, setting their `height` will be the min-height as tables will expand if the content stretches them.

Answer (score 0):

Setting height on table cells only works correctly, if your td is not using `box-sizing: border-box`. With border-box it will stay the height you set and content will overflow.
Use `content-box`or something else.
I ran into this problem because I used a css-resetter.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the css entry of min-height to one of the cells of your table row. Works on old browsers too.

```
.rowNumberColumn {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    min-height: 22;
}

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="htmlgrid-table">
    <tr id="tr_0">
            <td width="3%" align="center" class="readOnlyCell rowNumberColumn">1</td>
            <td align="left" width="40%" id="td_0_0" class="readOnlyCell gContentSection">411978430-Intimate:Ruby:Small</td>
```