# Is it possible to set min-width for td in a table. if possible, then how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to set min-height for td in a table. 
where inside the td only text is present.
if possible,then say how?

Comment: set it in css..

Comment: or by javascript..

Comment: See this link [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432092/can-i-use-a-min-height-for-table-tr-or-td)

Comment: is it possible to set min-height ??

Comment: title says `min-width` but in content `min-height` which is which?

Comment: min width or min height? sort out your question

Comment: sorry its belongs to min-height only, i need to know how to set min-height for td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes like this:

```
<td style="height:200px"></td>
```

Height property will act as min-height **if overflow is left *visible***

Comment: My bad - title was width, so i wrote that. I edited my answer now

Comment: yes its my fault, sorry for inconvenience. my requirement it to set min-height for 'td'. if set height property means it get fixed. other than this any other solution?

Comment: its works perfect, Thanks for your answer #NoOorZ24.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a div inside the td

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Your code</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
div {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes,you can do this 
for example:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>Lorem</div>
    </td>
</tr>
 div {
min-height: 300px;
 }
```

Comment: For this you have to put the content in a div and give min-height to a div