# X axis scrollbar hidden at the bottom inside of vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-good-table

Exactly as the title says, my overflow-x scrollbar is hidden at the bottom of the overflow y scrollbar. Is there anyway to fix this?

Right now the height and width are coming from the parent `.wrapper` div, but the `overflow-x`, while commented out, seems to be automatically set to scroll.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-table-filter-forked-pv2hko?file=/src/App.vue)

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <vue-good-table
      style="width: 100%"
      class="issue-tracker-style"
      :columns="columns"
      :rows="rows"
      :sort-options="{
        enabled: false,
      }"
    >
      <template v-slot:table-row="scope">
        <div>
          <div>{{ scope.formattedRow[scope.column.field] }}</div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </vue-good-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "my-component",
  mounted: function () {
    let tdElm;
    let startOffset;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
      document.querySelectorAll("table th"),
      function (td) {
        td.style.position = "relative";
        //td.style.maxWidth = "unset";
        let grip = document.createElement("div");
        grip.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
        grip.style.position = "absolute";
        grip.style.top = 0;
        grip.style.right = 0;
        grip.style.bottom = 0;
        grip.style.width = "5px";
        // grip.style.background = "red";
        grip.style.cursor = "col-resize";
        grip.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
          tdElm = td;
          startOffset = td.offsetWidth - e.pageX;
        });

        td.appendChild(grip);
      }
    );

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
      if (tdElm) {
        tdElm.style.minWidth = startOffset + e.pageX + "px";
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
      tdElm = undefined;
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      columns: [
        {
          label: "Name",
          field: "name",
          //width: "100px"
        },
        {
          label: "Age",
          field: "age",
          type: "number",
        },
        {
          label: "Created On",
          field: "createdAt",
          dateInputFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd",
          dateOutputFormat: "MMM do yy",
        },
        {
          label: "Percent",
          field: "score",
          type: "percentage",
        },
        {
          label: "Name",
          field: "name",
        },
        {
          label: "Age",
          field: "age",
          type: "number",
        },
        {
          label: "Created On",
          field: "createdAt",
          dateInputFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd",
          dateOutputFormat: "MMM do yy",
        },
        {
          label: "Percent",
          field: "score",
          type: "percentage",
        },
        {
          label: "Name",
          field: "name",
        },
        {
          label: "Age",
          field: "age",
          type: "number",
        },
        {
          label: "Created On",
          field: "createdAt",
          dateInputFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd",
          dateOutputFormat: "MMM do yy",
        },
        {
          label: "Percent",
          field: "score",
          type: "percentage",
        },
      ],
      rows: [
        { id: 1, name: "John", age: 20, createdAt: "", score: 0.03343 },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Jane Jacob Johnson OOOO",
          age: 24,
          createdAt: "2011-10-31",
          score: 0.03343,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Susan",
          age: 16,
          createdAt: "2011-10-30",
          score: 0.03343,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Chris",
          age: 55,
          createdAt: "2011-10-11",
          score: 0.03343,
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Dan",
          age: 40,
          createdAt: "2011-10-21",
          score: 0.03343,
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "John",
          age: 20,
          createdAt: "2011-10-31",
          score: 0.03343,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Susan",
          age: 16,
          createdAt: "2011-10-30",
          score: 0.03343,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Chris",
          age: 55,
          createdAt: "2011-10-11",
          score: 0.03343,
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Dan",
          age: 40,
          createdAt: "2011-10-21",
          score: 0.03343,
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "John",
          age: 20,
          createdAt: "2011-10-31",
          score: 0.03343,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style lang="scss">
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* overflow-x: scroll; */
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
.issue-tracker-style {
  font-family: "Inter";
  width: 100%;
  .vgt-inner-wrap {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  td > div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  td > div > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  thead {
    border: 1px solid #f0f7ff;
  }
  tr {
    background: white;
    margin: 0;
    height: 32px; // height works like min-height apparently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432092/can-i-use-a-min-height-for-table-tr-or-td/37115413
  }
  td {
    min-width: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -moz-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  tr th {
    color: #4859af;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #fafafa;
    border: 2px solid #efeff0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -moz-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  tr td {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #4859af;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #efeff0;
    height: 42px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  tr td,
  tr th {
    text-align: center;
  }
  /*tr th {
    width: 60px !important;
  }*/
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

this css should fix the problem

```
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
    width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.vgt-responsive {
  overflow: visible!important;
}
```

The scrollbar hidden at the bottom comes from the `.vgt-responsive`  class.

Comment: Holy cow, thank you! I cannot believe how simple of a fix that was!